# PHP Multiple thread remove duplicated

Tags: php, multithreading, pthreads

I want to create a class that can remove duplicate items but uses `pthreads` I have an `array` with some duplicated lines and put them into a thread each line and here is my code.

```
header("Content-type: text/plain");

class Arr {
    public $my_variable = array();

    public function add($value) {
        $this->my_variable[$value] = 1;
        return $this->my_variable;
    }

    public function check($value)
    {
        if(isset($this->my_variable[$value])){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

class workerThread extends Thread 
{
    public $arr;
    public function __construct($i){
        $this->i = str_replace("\r","",$i);
        $this->i = str_replace("\n","",$this->i);
        $this->arr = new Arr();
    }

    public function run()
    {
        if($this->arr->check($this->i)!==true)
        {
            $add = $this->arr->add($this->i);
            echo date('H:i:s') . ' - '. $this->i . " - (".count($add).")\r\n";
        }
    }
}


$mailExp = array(
    'talunays@gmail.com',
    'talunays@gmail.com',
    'talunays@gmail.com',
    'talunays@gmail.com',
    'talunays@gmail.com'
);
$total = count($mailExp);

for($i=0;$i<$total-1;$i++)
{
    $workers[$i]=new workerThread($mailExp[$i]);
    $workers[$i]->start();
}
```

But it doesn't work, duplicate lines still there and cannot be removed...

Comment: *What* does not work? Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 0):

You should use construct only to set your private $this variables.

Make the logic inside the run function and use array_unique.

Let the workers come back with join() and retrieve the unduplicated arrays at this point.